# BAPI_CUSTOMER_FIND parameter RESULT_TAB has strange structure

Tags: c#, sap-erp, bapi, sap-dotnet-connector

I need to search customers in SAP system from a C# application.
I'm using C# .NET connector.

I tried to call the BAPI `BAPI_CUSTOMER_FIND` to get all the customers with name that starts with "C" character, this is my code:

```
SAPConnectionConfigurator cfg = new SAPConnectionConfigurator();
RfcDestinationManager.RegisterDestinationConfiguration(cfg);
RfcDestination dest = RfcDestinationManager.GetDestination("mySAPdestination");
RfcRepository repo = dest.Repository;
IRfcFunction customerList = repo.CreateFunction("BAPI_CUSTOMER_FIND");
customerList.SetValue("MAX_CNT", "100");
IRfcTable searchFields = customerList.GetTable("SELOPT_TAB");
searchFields.Insert();
searchFields.CurrentRow.SetValue("COMP_CODE", "");
searchFields.CurrentRow.SetValue("TABNAME", "KNA1");
searchFields.CurrentRow.SetValue("FIELDNAME", "NAME1");
searchFields.CurrentRow.SetValue("FIELDVALUE", "C*");
customerList.Invoke(dest);
IRfcTable results = customerList.GetTable("RESULT_TAB");
```

The call works correctly but I don't know how to read the result. I need a list of customers but the `RESULT_TAB` table has this strange structure:

```
comp_code    bukrs       char(4)     Company Code 
tabname      tabname     char(30)    Table Name 
fieldname    fieldname   char(30)    Field Name 
fieldvalue   fieldvalue  char(132)   Field value 
customer     kunnr       char(10)    Customer Number 
pstg_blk_g   sperb_x     char(1)     Central posting block 
pstg_blk_c   sperb_b     char(1)     Posting block for company code 
del_flag_g   loevm_x     char(1)     Central Deletion Flag for Master Record 
del_flag_c   loevm_b     char(1)     Deletion Flag for Master Record (Company Code Level) 
type         bapi_mtype  char(1)     Message type: S Success, E Error, W Warning, I Info, A Abort 
id           symsgid     char(20)    Message Class 
number       symsgno     numc(3)     Message Number 
message      bapi_msg    char(220)   Message Text 
log_no       balognr     char(20)    Application Log: Log Number 
log_msg_no   balmnr      numc(6)     Application Log: Internal Message Serial Number 
message_v1   symsgv      char(50)    Message Variable 
message_v2   symsgv      char(50)    Message Variable 
message_v3   symsgv      char(50)    Message Variable 
message_v4   symsgv      char(50)    Message Variable
```

How can I get customers list? Am I calling the wrong BAPI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely didn't get any results, in that case table `RESULT_TAB` contains only one row with your original search parameters and a warning message. You need to set parameter `PL_HOLD` to `'X'` to allow using placeholders.

When there are results, you'll see several lines in table `RESULT_TAB`, with field `FIELDVALUE` containing the actual customer name (because you searched in field `NAME1` - change the search field and the result changes too) and `CUSTOMER` containing the customer number.

If there are more results than set in `MAX_CNT,` you'll see a message type `I`, ID `FN`, Number `063`  in the *last row* of your result set (with a message in your logon language telling you there are more than X results).

If your search didn't yield any results at all, the structure `RETURN` will contain a warning message (message type `W`, ID `FN`, number `802`) and the single row in table `RESULT_TAB` should contain another warning message type `W`, ID `FN`, number `065` and an explanatory message text in your logon language telling you there were no accounts found in your search.

In case you're wondering how to read an `IRfcTable` at all, you can just iterate over its contents. It is essentially a list of IRfcStructure items.

```
foreach(IRfcStructure row in returnTable) 
{
     var customerNumber = row.GetString("CUSTOMER");
}
```

Comment: Is it possible call a BAPI with a list of CUSTOMERNUMBER and receive back all the details of the custumers (list of custumers)?

Comment: That is unlikely. Typically SAP BAPIs either provide a basic list based on some search parameters or detailed information on a single object.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to add to Dirk answer. I just want to share an example of execution, for information, which I obtained from my SAP system.

Input parameters:

- `MAX_CNT`: 10
- `PL_HOLD`: 'X'
- `SELOPT_TAB` (for information, below corresponds to SQL `SELECT KUNNR AS CUSTOMER FROM KNA1 WHERE NAME1 LIKE 'C%'`):

  ```
  TABNAME  FIELDNAME  FIELDVALUE
  -------  ---------  ----------
  KNA1     NAME1      C*
  ```

Output parameters (after execution, 10 out of 20 lines in `KNA1` were extracted from SAP database):

- `RETURN`:

  ```
  TYPE  ID  NUMBER  MESSAGE
  ----  --  ------  -----------------------
  S     FN  800     No errors have occurred
  ```
- `RESULT_TAB`:

  ```
  TABNAME  FIELDNAME  FIELDVALUE          CUSTOMER    TYPE  ID  NUMBER  MESSAGE                                       MESSAGE_V1
  -------  ---------  ------------------  ----------  ----  --  ------  --------------------------------------------  ----------
  KNA1     NAME1      Corinne             0000000056  S     FN  800     No errors have occurred                               
  KNA1     NAME1      CUSTOMER 2 waldorf  0000000057  S     FN  800     No errors have occurred                               
  KNA1     NAME1      CUSTOMER 2 waldorf  0000000058  S     FN  800     No errors have occurred                               
  KNA1     NAME1      CUSTOMER 1 waldorf  0000000059  S     FN  800     No errors have occurred                               
  KNA1     NAME1      CUSTOMER 1 waldorf  0000000061  S     FN  800     No errors have occurred                               
  KNA1     NAME1      CUSTOMER 2 waldorf  0000000141  S     FN  800     No errors have occurred                               
  KNA1     NAME1      Corinne Schneller   0000000182  S     FN  800     No errors have occurred                               
  KNA1     NAME1      Customer master11   6000000007  S     FN  800     No errors have occurred                               
  KNA1     NAME1      Customer master111  6000000008  S     FN  800     No errors have occurred                               
  KNA1     NAME1      Customer master1    6000000011  I     FN  063     There are more than        10 search results        10
  ```